# Applying Ecto validate_length on multiple fields in Changeset

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

Ecto 3.2.5, Phoenix 1.4.11, Elixir 1.9.4

I have an Ecto Changeset that looks something like this. I have numerous fields that I would like to run `validate_length` on all with the same max length.

```
my_model
|> validate_required(required_fields())
|> validate_length(:field, max: 255)
|> validate_length(:another_field, max: 255)
# More of the same validate_length
```

Instead of listing one-by-one I also tried something along these lines of this with my Changeset after the piping above, without luck.

```
Enum.map([:field, :another_field], fn string_field ->
  Ecto.Changeset.validate_length(ch, string_field, max: 255)
end)
```

`validate_length` only takes a single field by default, so how can I validate length on multiple fields without a line-by-line `validate_length`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Enum.map/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/master/Enum.html?#map/2) would not work because what you actually are to perform would be to *reduce* changeset on many fields via validation.

Simply declare the normal private function like the below

```rb
@spec validate_length_many(
  changeset :: Ecto.Changeset.t(), fields :: [atom()]
) :: Ecto.Changeset.t()
defp validate_length_many(
  %Ecto.Changeset{} = changeset, fields
) when is_list(fields) do
  Enum.reduce(fields, changeset, fn field, changeset ->
    validate_length(changeset, field, max: 255)
  end)
end
```

and use it as

```rb
my_model
|> validate_required(required_fields())
|> validate_length_many(~w[f1 f2]a)
```

or call [`Enum.reduce/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/master/Enum.html?#reduce/3) directly (it won’t pipe well because the first argument in the call to [`Enum.reduce/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/master/Enum.html?#reduce/3) would be a list of fields).

```rb
changeset = validate_required(my_model, required_fields())
Enum.reduce([:f1, :f2], changeset, fn field, changeset ->
  validate_length(changeset, field, max: 255)
end) #⇒ changeset
```